# iSCSI Volume shown as two partitions on disk manager and need to merge/extend

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, iscsi, diskpart

I've just created a LUN and Target on my NAS, the from windows server, used iSCSI initiator to mount it.

Disk appears in disk manager Disabled.

Using `diskpart` i remove readonly attrib and created partition for the size of the disk (unalloc)

diskpart threw an exception:

```
No usable free extent could be found. It may be that there is insufficient
free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. Specify
different size and offset values or don't specify either to create the
maximum sized partition. It may be that the disk is partitioned using the MBR disk 
partitioning format and the disk contains either 4 primary partitions, (no
more partitions may be created), or 3 primary partitions and one extended
partition, (only logical drives may be created).
```

And still went on to split the drive.

[image]

`diskpart` .. `select disk=6` .. `list partition` shows none.

How can i "merge" these partitions and create a single simple volume?

I've tried quite a few things from creating the LUN to various diskpart ops.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found a solution

```
diskpart
select disk=6
clean
convert GPT
```

MBR default 2TB limit.

Thanks